# SPFX in Teams - red badge icon in left column?

Tags: spfx, microsoft-teams

I am creating SPFX based webpart which is deployed to Teams as application. The icon appears in the left column in Teams. Is it possible to notify user when something is happening in the app or data like the native Teams apps can do? I would like to show a red badge on the icon to visualize there is some action for the user.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the only way to notify users is to send activity feed notifications. These will surface in the Activity ring bell icon as opposed to your app's icon.

[Send activity feed notifications to users in Microsoft Teams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications)

> The Microsoft Teams activity feed enables users to triage items that require attention by notifying them of changes

Comment: Thank you very much, Denis. I already tried that approach, it is working but not exactly what I was hoping for :) So maybe in the future we will have a native option for red badge over the icon.